# Android tabs icons

Tags: android, menu, tabs, icons

I have 2 questions:
1. I have an activity with 3 tabs. I want an icon on each an icon. I've got 32x32 icons. When i place them on a tab and run my app with the emulator, the icons are blurred. But when I open the icons on my pc they are just fine. 
2. I have the same problem with the options menu. When I place an icon on a option of the options menu and run the app with the emulator the icons are blurred. But when I open the icons on my pc they are just fine.

Does somebody have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try to increase your tab vertical size in the layout, because icons become blurry when there's not enough space and Android has to rescale them to fit.

Answer (score 0):

There you get resized icons, you  can upload yours and will get them in the right size

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-tab.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0.05&name=example

and her you see the desing lines

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab.html